# Hyperledger composer rest server : Error trying to ping. Error: No peers available to query. last error was Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connect Failed

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Under Hyperledger composer, I am trying to set up a persistent Rest Server using googleauth2.0 over a multi-org setup.

For the multi-org setup, I have followed https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org and for the google auth setup I have followed https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/google_oauth2_rest.

Everything goes fine until following step when I try to start a new instance of the extended Docker image for the REST server using following command

```
docker run
-d
-e COMPOSER_CARD=${COMPOSER_CARD}
-e COMPOSER_NAMESPACES=${COMPOSER_NAMESPACES}
-e COMPOSER_AUTHENTICATION=${COMPOSER_AUTHENTICATION}
-e COMPOSER_MULTIUSER=${COMPOSER_MULTIUSER}
-e COMPOSER_PROVIDERS="${COMPOSER_PROVIDERS}"
-e COMPOSER_DATASOURCES="${COMPOSER_DATASOURCES}"
-v ~/.composer:/home/composer/.composer
--name rest
--network composer_default
-p 3001:3001
org1/composer-rest-server
```

Following are the logs from rest container:

```
[2018-05-13 02:38:15] PM2 log: Launching in no daemon mode
[2018-05-13 02:38:16] PM2 log: Starting execution sequence in -fork mode- for app name:composer-rest-server id:0
[2018-05-13 02:38:16] PM2 log: App name:composer-rest-server id:0 online
WARNING: NODE_APP_INSTANCE value of '0' did not match any instance config file names.
WARNING: See https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Strict-Mode
Discovering types from business network definition ...
Connection fails: Error: Error trying to ping. Error: No peers available to query. last error was Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connect Failed
It will be retried for the next request.
Exception: Error: Error trying to ping. Error: No peers available to query. last error was Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connect Failed
Error: Error trying to ping. Error: No peers available to query. last error was Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connect Failed
    at _checkRuntimeVersions.then.catch (/home/composer/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-connector-hlfv1/lib/hlfconnection.js:790:34)
    at <anonymous>
[2018-05-13 02:38:29] PM2 log: App [composer-rest-server] with id [0] and pid [14], exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
```

Here are the docker containers:

```
233938f12ef0        org1/composer-rest-server                                                                                "pm2-docker composer…"   30 minutes ago      Up 30 minutes       3000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3001->3001/tcp                   rest
6285853fdceb        dev-peer1.org1.example.com-emcs-0.0.3-b1bb3a7f1090c0d1cabf10340188aa72e329e1266595f63d232d9cc38a0ed8b8   "/bin/sh -c 'cd /usr…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour                                                       dev-peer1.org1.example.com-emcs-0.0.3
1a4f7680cac9        dev-peer0.org1.example.com-emcs-0.0.3-094e3600469176994df7048ec5afad4114ce5203fe267b0c45da52a3d3b9e0b7   "/bin/sh -c 'cd /usr…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour                                                       dev-peer0.org1.example.com-emcs-0.0.3
b7c7364c88bd        dev-peer0.org2.example.com-emcs-0.0.3-3f76658cf8352417e15be589ed41aa0fa81e702a1bdb6e7e1ce898a015fdd34c   "/bin/sh -c 'cd /usr…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour                                                       dev-peer0.org2.example.com-emcs-0.0.3
b154cd4f50bd        dev-peer1.org2.example.com-emcs-0.0.3-340eb1dbb0152185d068724d637848c882bd3754f7c9888d57c80bdfb6530774   "/bin/sh -c 'cd /usr…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour                                                       dev-peer1.org2.example.com-emcs-0.0.3
f9d2a72fde40        dev-peer1.org2.example.com-mycc-1.0-26c2ef32838554aac4f7ad6f100aca865e87959c9a126e86d764c8d01f8346ab     "chaincode -peer.add…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours                                                             dev-peer1.org2.example.com-mycc-1.0
d812bef3a1bd        dev-peer0.org1.example.com-mycc-1.0-384f11f484b9302df90b453200cfb25174305fce8f53f4e94d45ee3b6cab0ce9     "chaincode -peer.add…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours                                                             dev-peer0.org1.example.com-mycc-1.0
ccb70e752d7b        dev-peer0.org2.example.com-mycc-1.0-15b571b3ce849066b7ec74497da3b27e54e0df1345daff3951b94245ce09c42b     "chaincode -peer.add…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours                                                             dev-peer0.org2.example.com-mycc-1.0
6989f8850296        hyperledger/fabric-tools                                                                                 "/bin/bash -c './scr…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours                                                             cli
0eabbd6be684        hyperledger/fabric-peer                                                                                  "peer node start"        2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:10051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:10053->7053/tcp   peer1.org2.example.com
d8c1146a5989        hyperledger/fabric-peer                                                                                  "peer node start"        2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:8051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8053->7053/tcp     peer1.org1.example.com
142aeb4525ab        hyperledger/fabric-peer                                                                                  "peer node start"        2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:9051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9053->7053/tcp     peer0.org2.example.com
70ef571ea1ba        hyperledger/fabric-peer                                                                                  "peer node start"        2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp     peer0.org1.example.com
31c8417beae2        hyperledger/fabric-ca                                                                                    "sh -c 'fabric-ca-se…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:8054->7054/tcp                             ca_peerOrg2
ade3061fc517        hyperledger/fabric-orderer                                                                               "orderer"                2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp                             orderer.example.com
e315be1721d9        hyperledger/fabric-couchdb                                                                               "tini -- /docker-ent…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8984->5984/tcp         couchdb3
0197051ffaf6        hyperledger/fabric-couchdb                                                                               "tini -- /docker-ent…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:6984->5984/tcp         couchdb1
5abd60481ec3        hyperledger/fabric-couchdb                                                                               "tini -- /docker-ent…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7984->5984/tcp         couchdb2
58205a7b26fe        hyperledger/fabric-ca                                                                                    "sh -c 'fabric-ca-se…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp                             ca_peerOrg1
13009c1401fb        hyperledger/fabric-couchdb                                                                               "tini -- /docker-ent…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5984->5984/tcp         couchdb0
1ef9ab29b607        mongo                                                                                                    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp                           mongo
```

I have already gone through some errors which have been received by others, and so have already performed following additional steps:

1. Changing the permissions of ~/.composer by using the command: chmod
   -R 777 ~/.composer
2. Replaced the IP addresses in the connection.json for my network cards to use 0.0.0.0 as recommended
   in https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/3002.

I have tried cleaning up all my docker containers and images, stopping the fabric and starting the fabric but it still comes up with the same error..

Expected behaviour is that the command docker logs -f rest should finish with Browse your REST API at http://localhost:3001/explorer. However, it results in the above error.

Answer (score 2):

The Google Auth tutorial isn't expecting a fabric set up from the multiorg tutorial so isn't going to work if you follow the steps. The Auth tutorial is designed to work with the single org provided by the development fabric from setting up the composer development environment or running the single org tutorial. The problem will be that the connection.json needs to describe the multi-org setup (so you will need an appropriate connection profile from the multi-org tutorial) and as you are running your rest server in a docker container and are attaching to the network which all the hyperledger fabric containers are connected to you cannot use hostnames and addresses such as `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` or `0.0.0.0` to try to address the different hyperledger fabric processes (all of these will actually refer to your rest server container). You need to use the correct hostnames to identify them. For example

> orderer.example.com for the orderer
>
> peer0.org1.example.com for peer0.org1.example.com (and similar for the other peers)
>
> ca0 for the certificate authority in org1, ca1 for the certificate authority in org2

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing your `peer0.org1.example.com`, `peer0.org1.example.com`, `ca.org1.example.com` and `orderer.example.com` in

```
sed -e 's/localhost:7051/peer0.org1.example.com:7051/' \
    -e 's/localhost:7053/peer0.org1.example.com:7053/' \
    -e 's/localhost:7054/ca.org1.example.com:7054/' \
    -e 's/localhost:7050/orderer.example.com:7050/' \
    < $HOME/.composer/cards/restadmin@trade-network/connection.json \
    > /tmp/connection.json && \
    cp -p /tmp/connection.json $HOME/.composer/cards/restadmin@trade-network/
```

command with your ip adddress like :

```
sed -e 's/localhost:7051/192.168.0.170:7051/' \
    -e 's/localhost:7053/192.168.0.170:7053/' \
    -e 's/localhost:7054/192.168.0.170:7054/' \
    -e 's/localhost:7050/192.168.0.170:7050/' \
    < $HOME/.composer/cards/restadmin@trade-network/connection.json \
    > /tmp/connection.json && \
    cp -p /tmp/connection.json $HOME/.composer/cards/restadmin@trade-network/
```

Comment: You should format your code. See [How do I format my code blocks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361)?